# XHR Update fails with string containing a "#" where form post succeeds

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm moving away from standard form posts (to PHP PDO) to asynchronous XHR posts to update a mysql database (again PHP PDO), using prepared statements calling mysql stored procedures.

Using HTMLSpecialCharacters / UTF-8 etc. to sanitise inputs (both in XHR version and form post version). Also setting charset=utf8 in my PDO connection string.

The problem is that if I pass the XHR version a string containing a "#", the update fails. The returned error SQLSTATE[23000] indicates that a completely separate column cannot be null (as per table constraint).

There are several fields being inputted and regardless of which contains the "#", the same null constraint is violated.

Note that the field being set to null is the last being set with $stmt->bindvalue.

Also, I'm using $_GET[] in the bind values, not $_POST which was the issue in a similar question.

I understand that I could replace the "#" on write and put it back on read (I'm already doing this with line breaks) but I've a sneaky suspicion that I'm missing something fundamental here (I'm a bit new to AJAX and PHP).

There are no issues with "#" (or line breaks for that matter) in the standard form post.

TIA for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Yay... I figured it out, or to be honest I gave up and tried a different method. Instead of posting the values as part of the url with the content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, I posted the data as json using content-type = application/json.

Not only has the problem gone away, but I've no more need to find and replace line breaks and #s.

The json approach seems the most logical, and the least painful.